# Pass data from View to Controller (I really don't know what it could be)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass data from the view to controller with Html.beginform. The caregiverid is null. This should work but I don't know what I do wrong. I also checked the variable names, but it is the same.

I also tested, if the viewbag is filled with data. The viewbag is filled with the correct data.

This is the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PairClient", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-md-12", caregiverid = ViewBag.caregiverid }))
{
    <select name="clientselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count > 4" data-multiple-separator=" | " data-none-selected-text="Niks geselecteerd" data-deselect-all-text="Niks" data-select-all-text="Alles" data-count-selected-text="{0} clienten geselecteerd" data-width="100%" data-size="10" multiple>
        @foreach (var client in Model)
        {
            <option style="font-size:15px;" value="@client.ClientId" selected="@(client.IsSelected ? "selected" : null)" data-tokens="@client.Email">@client.SocialNumber - @client.Firstname @client.Lastname</option>
        }
    </select>
    <input class="btn btn-success " type="submit" value="Koppel cliënt" />
}
```

This is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PairClient(string caregiverid, string[] clientselect)
{
    string token = Request.Cookies["userToken"];
    admin.PairClient(token, caregiverid, clientselect);
    return RedirectToAction("Singlecaregiver");
}
```

It worked! I do not know what I have changed... but somehow it worked

Comment: Your controller needs to accept a view model, not 2 seperate variables

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a multiple select list work with model binding in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255472/how-does-a-multiple-select-list-work-with-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I just want to have the caregiverId, This has nothing to do with the option values

Comment: @TheProgrammer You should add that to the question.  It wasn't immediately clear.

Comment: You could use an ajax call. Do an onSubmit on the Html form and if you just want to send the caregiverId, use a json and send it to a controller method using ajax

Comment: Within the `using` block, add `@Html.Hidden("caregiverid", ViewBag.caregiverid)`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hidden HTML tag eg.

```
<input type="hidden" name="caregiverid" id="caregiverid" value="@ViewBag.caregiverid"/>
```

In your controller, you are expecting a string array of client selected, but is the data in the select field an array?

Try and set the "multiple" attribute on your select element, or write each selection to a hidden field with and post it make sure each element has the same name as the method signature. eg.

```
<input type="hidden" name="clientselect"/>
```

Also on your controller update it to this and try

```
public IActionResult PairClient([FromForm] string caregiverid, [FromForm] string[] clientselect)
```

Comment: I just need the caregiverId in a string. Nothing else :). Not the entire array or something

Comment: I've updated my post, just add the hidden input tag with the name caregiverid and a vlaue of @ViewBag.caregiverid

Comment: eg. <input type="hidden" name="caregiverid" id="caregiverid" value="@ViewBag.caregiverid"/>

Comment: I did that yea, but the string is still empty, I am thinking to just make a caregivermodel and send that to the view ;p, So I send the whole model instead of just a string

Comment: if you inspect the element does it have the data in the value attribute? 
also update  add this to you controller

public IActionResult PairClient([FromForm] string caregiverid, [FromForm] string[] clientselect)

Comment: [FromForm] tells the model binder where to look for the data to bind it. So in this case it's looking for data in the form for an element named caregiverid.

you also get [FromBody] , [FromQuery] (from querystring)

Comment: I added that but it does not work , I did not include a model for caregiverid

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried your Code and just modified it a bit and managed to get the data moved to the controller so please just copy paste the following code and all will be well

HTML

```
@using WebApplication1.Models;
@model IReadOnlyCollection<Client>`@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>`
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-md-12" }))
{ 
<select name="clientselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count > 4" data-multiple-separator=" | " data-none-selected-text="Niks geselecteerd" data-deselect-all-text="Niks" data-select-all-text="Alles" data-count-selected-text="{0} clienten geselecteerd" data-width="100%" data-size="10" multiple>
       @foreach (var client in Model)
    {
        <option style="font-size:15px;" value="@client.ClientId" selected="@(client.IsSelected ? "selected" : null)" 
                data-tokens="@client.Email">@client.SocialNumber - @client.Firstname @client.Lastname</option>
    }
    </select>
<input type="hidden" name="caregiverid" id="caregiverid" value="@ViewBag.caregiverid" />
<input class="btn btn-success " type="submit" value="Koppel cliënt" />
}
```

[image]
This is an image of the controller that i added to the project and as you can see caregiverid is set to 1 and two clients have been selected. hope this solved your problem.

But i do recommend that you change from that code in the controller to something similar to this [image]

Comment: Thank you for your anser. i don't know what I did. But it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<select name="clientselect[]" ...` (notice `[]`) to your `select` tag.

Like here: https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/8725/How-to-add-a-multi-select-drop-down-in-Modal