# How to insert dan update value from HTML <select> multiple Attributes in ASP.NET MVC to database?

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I input multiple values to the database from HTML  multiple Attributes? In this problem I want to input multiple values in MultiSelectList in one column in the database table, namely the Pages column. And then about the form update to display the options that have been previously selected? I am using ASP.NET MVC with a MySQL database. Thank's

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="box-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="CreatePage">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
               <td>Page</td>
               <td><select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" name="Page">
                   <option value="Home">Home</option>
                   <option value="About">About</option>
                   <option value="Profile">Profile</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>                
      <div class="box-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

CreateController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePage(MasterPage Page)
{
    db.MasterPage.Add(Page);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

MasterPage.cs

```
public partial class MasterPage
{
   public string Page { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string[]` array or  `List<string>`, for sending multiple attributes values.

For more details check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255472/how-does-a-multiple-select-list-work-with-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

> View Code

```
<div class="box-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="CreatePage">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
               <td>Page</td>
               <td><select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" name="Page">
                   <option value="Home">Home</option>
                   <option value="About">About</option>
                   <option value="Profile">Profile</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>                
      <div class="box-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

> Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePage(List<string> Page)
{           
    if (Page != null)
    {
        foreach(var item in Page)
        {
            db.MasterPage.Add(new MasterPage(){ Page = item});
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send them to back-end comma separated like page1,page2,page3 or the easy better way create table lookup that contain all the pages with IDs and store just the IDs in database